# c# Iterate over var with value obtained with GetValue()

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime

In an MVC 5 c# application, I am attempting to extract values from objects at runtime using strings for property names. The process works fine until the value extracted is a collection. I am unable to write the code to iterate over the extracted value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;               
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Student student = new Student { 
             Lectures = new List<Lecture>{ 
                new Lecture { Title="Science"},
                new Lecture {Title="Math"}
             }
        };
        
        var obj = student;
        string fld = "Lectures";

        // The following code knows nothing about Students or Lectures
        // It does know that the "fld" is a property name of "obj" that contains a collection

        var items = obj.GetType().GetProperty(fld).GetValue(obj);
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            // Code to process item
        }
    }
}

public class Lecture
{
     public string Title {get;set;}
}

public class Student
{
   public List<Lecture> Lectures {get;set;}
}
```

The above "for" instruction is flagged as a syntax error with the red highlight on "items". The error indicates that it cannot operate on variables of type "object" because "object" does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator.

Pasting the above code into https://dotnetfiddle.net illustrates the issue.

Is what I attempting possible? When debugging, "items" does show as a collection of Lecture.

Comment: Any particular reason to do this with reflection?

Comment: Using `foreach` requires that you have a collection, i.e., that the static type of the variable you wish to enumerate is enumerable.  In the debugger, check the type of the object to which `items` refers.  It is very likely a `List<Lecture>`.  Cast it appropriately (say to `IEnumerable<Lecture>`) and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

[GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-propertyinfo-getvalue(system-object)) returns type object, which doesn't know that it is a `List<Lecture>`. You need to cast to your target type:

```
var items = obj.GetType().GetProperty(fld).GetValue(obj) as List<Lecture>;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);
    // Code to process item
}
```

Comment: You probably want to wrap the `foreach` with a null check on `items`